# Genymotion Initialize Engine: failed in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, genymotion

I downloaded Genymotion and Genymotion IntelliJ plugin. I set Genymotion path in Intellij. Instructions: https://cloud.genymotion.com/page/doc/#collapse-intellij

When I try to relaunch plugin I get the following error:

```
4:36:22 PM Genymotion: Loading Genymotion library
4:36:22 PM Genymotion: Genymotion directory: /Applications/Genymotion.app/Contents/MacOS
4:36:22 PM Genymotion: Trying to initialize engine
4:36:23 PM Genymotion: Initialize Engine: failed
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you use the JetBrains repositories method of installation?

Comment: Yep! Followed the instructions to a T.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Surprisingly not much on the [internet](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Genymotion%3a%20Initialize%20Engine%3a%20failed%22#q=Genymotion%3a%20%22Initialize%20Engine%3a%20failed%22) about this. If you were to just run Genymotion (standalone) you'd get the nice error message:

> Unable to load VirtualBox engine.
>
> Make sure that you have installed it correctly before starting
>   Genymotion.
>
> For more information, refer to
>   https://cloud.genymotion.com/page/faq#vbox

Unfortunately you won't see this in IntelliJ's Event Log. Once you install virtual box you should be all set.

Answer (score 11):

Download and install Virtual Box for your platform and it will work. 
Download from https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads .

Comment: Sorry, it does not help. You need to install VirtualBox no later than 4.2 to fix issue

Answer (score 2):

First it seemed like the case is path to Genymotion, but
this error is caused by a bug that does not let Genymotion plugin work with VirtualBox later than 4.2

To fix this error all you need to do is go here:
https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Download_Old_Builds_4_2
and download the 4.2 version of VirtualBox. Once you reinstall it - the error is gone and Genymotion plugin opens device list properly

Answer (score 0):

With Genymotion 1.0.5 release, it works well VirtualBox 5.x on OSX platform. Please upgrade plugin to latest.

https://www.genymotion.com/#!/release-notes/253_p105

Answer (score 0):

So I have faced the same issue, been online searching for an answer with very little help. what I have done is, completely uninstall Genymotion and Vbox, did a restart of my machine, redownloaded, the newer version ( 2.5.4) of Genymotion with Vbox included from https://www.genymotion.com and then did a fresh install, this seems to have fixed the issue.