# Genymotion error : Initialize Engine: failed

Tags: java, android, android-studio, genymotion, androidstudio-settings

when i try to run my app on **Android Studio** by **Genymotion plugin** it gives me this error :

> Genymotion: Loading Genymotion library  Genymotion: Genymotion
>   directory: D:\معتصم\Genymotion  Genymotion: Trying to initialize
>   engine  Genymotion: vboxPath: D:\?????\VB\VBoxManage.exe  Genymotion:
>   Launch process: D:\?????\VB\VBoxManage.exe --version  Genymotion:
>   Exception (D:\?????\VB\VBoxManage.exe)  Genymotion: Initialize Engine:
>   failed

[image]

and when i opened **Genymotion.exe** from **Genymotion** folder and started the **virtual device** it opened without any item just white sceeen

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Genymotion Initialize Engine: failed in IntelliJ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19799612/genymotion-initialize-engine-failed-in-intellij)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set genymotion path in android studio to open genymotion emulator from studio extension.

You have to enter it inside the **Android Studio settings**, under **Genymotion** section.

by default windows path for genymotion is `C:\Program Files\Genymobile\Genymotion`

Download and install Virtual Box if not installed for your platform from https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads .